# Forward converter - How to measure the equivalent leakage inductane of this model?

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, electromagnetism

Here is the schematic that I found in an old AN from UNITRODE. https://www.smps.us/slup199.pdf

[image]

Here is the equivalent schematic showing the magnetizing inductance and the leakage inductances:

[image]

This is pretty simple to find the equivalent magnetizing inductance, nevertheless it is a bit more complicated to understand what are the leakage inductances in a real transformer (at least to me). Lp1 is the leakage inductance between the primary and the main secondary V1. L12' is the leakage inductance between the main secondary (V1) and the second secondary (V2). Actually I do not even understand what is in a real transformer what is the leakage inductance between the main secondary (V1) and the second secondary (V2) as the flux leakage has a meaning between primary and secondaries.

Here is the equivalent model of a transformer (unfortunately with one ouptut):

[image]

I know that I can measure the leakage inductance of the primary or of the secondary by shorting the primary or the secondary in order to apply 0V across the magnetizing inductance. (Actually this measure do some approximation as we can see. If you know a better method I will be glad to hear it)

In any case, where is Lp1 in the transformer model? How to find Lp1? If we supposed that the output V2 does not exist it seems that Lp1 is equal to the sum of the leakage inductance at the primary and at the secondary.

$$Lp1 = LprimaryLeakage + LmainSecondaryLeakage$$

For L12', I would say that the leakage inductance would be equal to:

$$L12' = \frac{N1²}{N2²}*(LsecondaryLeakage - LmainSecondaryLeakage)$$

What do you think about it?

Comment: V2 has to exist - without V2 existing there is no secondary winding and leakage inductance is meaningless. Please take this on-board and edit your question to remove that once you have comprehended it. I'm also struggling to see what relevance there is in the diagrams from Unitrode. They don't appear to bring anything to the party. Can this stuff be removed to make your question less-complex to follow to the point where you are beginning to ask proper questions?

Comment: Not entirely sure where your confusion is, but the equivalent transformer model you have found it chosen is overly complex for your needs here. If you “dumb it down” to one with just magnitizing inductance on the primary and leakage on the secondary and try again, does it improve the situation and your understanding?

Comment: Hi :) if V1 exists without V2 there is still one secondary winding. I'm not talking about Vs in the electrical transformer model. The purpose of my question is to define by a relation Lp and L12' in the diagrams from Unitrode. I need to express Lp and L12's thank to the elements of a real transformer, ie the electrical transformer model. Is it more clear ?

Comment: Winny, thank you for your comment :) It doesn't change anything to me unfortunately. I know that  the model includes more details that my question needs...